# Sass mixin recursion; @include loop

Tags: css, ruby, recursion, sass

Does anyone know if it's possible to revert Sass's functionality, to prevent the "bug-fix"<sup>1</sup> that was implemented to prevent `@include` recursion?

The message is:

`Syntax error: An @include loop has been found: <mixin-name> includes itself`

This was "fixed"<sup>1</sup> in [3.0.5](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_CHANGELOG.html#305), and I'd prefer not to (*read: I can't*) downgrade that far. I unfortunately don't know enough Ruby to go sifting through the source, and while I'm making time to change that, it doesn't help me now.

So, is it possible<sup>2</sup> to revert this functionality to that of pre-3.0.5 without having to downgrade; is there a re-patch floating around somewhere? I haven't been able to find one.

**Edit:** While I've answered this myself now, I'm still open to better answers; specifically, more portable solutions since now the Sass files will break anywhere else (*anywhere that isn't pre-3.0.5*)

<sub><sup>1</sup> Quotes used to indicate I don't think this is a fix. I think it is a break; I'll take that up with those responsible though.

<sup>2</sup> <strike>I know its possible, but I mean specifically for someone with no practical experience with Ruby.</strike> I'm learning Ruby!</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, there's a cleaner way apply your hack: [monkey-patching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) with [Compass](http://compass-style.org/).

It will let you share your project safely and everybody else will be able to compile it without modifying their own SASS compilers.

### 1)

Create `sass-visit-mixin-monkey-patch.rb` next to `compass.rb` and apply your hack from there:

```
class Sass::Tree::Visitors::Perform < Sass::Tree::Visitors::Base
  # Runs a mixin.
  def visit_mixin(node)
    #include_loop = true
    #handle_include_loop!(node) if @stack.any? {|e| e[:name] == node.name}
    include_loop = false

    @stack.push(:filename => node.filename, :line => node.line, :name => node.name)
    raise Sass::SyntaxError.new("Undefined mixin '#{node.name}'.") unless mixin = @environment.mixin(node.name)

    if node.children.any? && !mixin.has_content
      raise Sass::SyntaxError.new(%Q{Mixin "#{node.name}" does not accept a content block.})
    end

    args = node.args.map {|a| a.perform(@environment)}
    keywords = Sass::Util.map_hash(node.keywords) {|k, v| [k, v.perform(@environment)]}
    splat = node.splat.perform(@environment) if node.splat

    self.class.perform_arguments(mixin, args, keywords, splat) do |env|
      env.caller = Sass::Environment.new(@environment)
      env.content = node.children if node.has_children

      trace_node = Sass::Tree::TraceNode.from_node(node.name, node)
      with_environment(env) {trace_node.children = mixin.tree.map {|c| visit(c)}.flatten}
      trace_node
    end
  rescue Sass::SyntaxError => e
    unless include_loop
      e.modify_backtrace(:mixin => node.name, :line => node.line)
      e.add_backtrace(:line => node.line)
    end
    raise e
  ensure
    @stack.pop unless include_loop
  end
end
```

### 2)

Require the monkey patch from the `config.rb`:

```
# Enabling mixin recursion by applying a monkey patch to SASS compiler
require "./sass-visit-mixin-monkey-patch"
```

### 3)

Compile your project with `compass compile`.

Comment: Really; so, you just redefine and require `visit_mixin` and that patches it. Ruby, you crazy.

Answer (score 1):

You know, I know enough Ruby to comment out a line or two ;)

At `.\lib\sass\tree\visitors\perform.rb : 249` just comment:

```
# Runs a mixin.
def visit_mixin(node)
  include_loop = true
  handle_include_loop!(node) if @stack.any? {|e| e[:name] == node.name}
  include_loop = false
```

Into:

```
# Runs a mixin.
def visit_mixin(node)
  # include_loop = true
  # handle_include_loop!(node) if @stack.any? {|e| e[:name] == node.name}
  include_loop = false
```

Suddenly, rainbows of glorious recursion.

Comment: Can you please provide a real-life example of a task for which recursion is such a good solution that it's worth hacking the SASS engine and producing code that will never work for anyone else?

Comment: There was an instance where I had several mixins participating in mutual recursion; however by design it was always finite. I'll provide an example in my question once I get home (*and have the project available*)

Comment: I don't ask for code. I ask for description of a task mases hacked recursion an appropriate solution.

Comment: @lolmaus Automatically name-prefixed classes using a global namespace stack. The mixins invoke push/pop functions against the namespace list before/after rendering the mixin `@content`. If a mixin is defined, containing code that calls these mixins, and is included in another block that using these utility mixins, since they're mutually recursive, the Sass engine borks. Also; I wouldn't call this hacked recursion, rather *un*-hacked; the imposed limitation is a bit of a hack if you ask me.

Comment: Can you please provide a list of the generated classes? I still don't see why rrecursion is necessary.

Comment: @lolmaus I assure you, recursion *becomes* necessary to reuse the mixins. This isn't an XY problem. Recursion should be allowed, plain and simple; there is no iterative solution. Speaking of which, do you happen to have any answers for me with respect to providing better support for re-implementing recursion?

Comment: Okay, you convinced me. I have posted a portable solution.