# How to ignore multiline comments in sass?

Tags: ruby, comments, sass

Is there a way to make sass ignore multiline comments when generating the css file:

```
// these comments are ignored
```

These are not (only ignored in compressed mode):

```
/*
 * multiline comments
 *
 */
```

I found this [ticket](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/338) on Github where the author says:

> If you really want, you can monkeypatch Sass to silence /* */ comments as well.

But I don't know what he means by monkeypatch sass, so how can I do this ?

Comment: Since all of your production CSS will be compressed/minified, out of curiosity why do you need this functionality?

Comment: If you use the `compressed` output format, no comments will be present in the generated CSS.

Comment: @bookcasey yes I know but I also want a compact and expanded versions of the css file without comments to distribute them, the current generated files contain unwanted and not in place comments and I have many imported sass files.

Comment: I know it's something I can workaround but I want to keep these comments in the original sass files.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yay! I've learned monkey patching SASS while answering this question:

[Sass mixin recursion; @include loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15531004/)

And now i can help you too!

### 1) Install Compass

For this solution to work, you'll need [Compass](http://compass-style.org/). Install it with:

```rb
gem install compass
```

### 2) Configure Compass

Create a `compass.rb` file in your project's root and define directories where you keep your SASS and CSS code, e. g.:

```rb
css_dir = "stylesheets"
sass_dir = "sass"
```

### 3) Create a [monkey patch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch)

Create a file called `remove-all-comments-monkey-patch.rb` in your project's root:

```rb
class Sass::Tree::Visitors::Perform < Sass::Tree::Visitors::Base

  # Removes all comments completely
  def visit_comment(node)
    return []
  end

end
```

### 4) Require the monkey patch from the `config.rb`

In the `config.rb`, add:

```rb
# Removing all comments by applying a monkey patch to SASS compiler
require "./remove-all-comments-monkey-patch"
```

### 5) Compile your project with Compass

Use `compass compile` to compile SASS into CSS. You can also use `compass watch` to make the Compass command line tool constantly monitor your code for changes and recompile parts that you modify.

### Considerations

This will not remove comments with line numbers generated by SASS. To disable them comment out the `line_comments = true` line in `config.rb` or set it to false.

To re-enable multiline comments, just comment out the line that requires the monkey patch and do `compass clean`.

### Don't use it! Use single-line comments with Ctrl+/.

Though this solution is portable and will work for everybody without hacking SASS code manually, you should really consider using an IDE that allows commenting out whole paragraphs with single-line comments using a single keystroke. For me it's `Ctrl`+`/`.

Here, i've filmed a short video for you to show that using line comments is actually quicker and more effective than using multiline comments: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=DTyMAPZrwyc

Line comments also let you comment out comments without breaking the code.

Consider you have the following code:

```css
foo

/* Bla bla */
bar

baz
```

And you need to comment it all out. If you wrap it all with `/* */`...

```css
/*foo

/* Bla bla */
bar

baz*/
```

...then you broke the code! Now you have a comment that starts with `/*foo` and ends with `bla */`, and also a syntax error at `baz*/`.

Instead, just select the whole code and hit `Ctrl`+`/` (provided that use some IDE or programmer's notepad), it will all be commented out immediately:

```cpp
//foo
//
///* Bla bla */
//bar
//
//baz
```

And of course it can later be uncommented with the same hotkey.

Comment: Is it possible to strip block comments only in partials (that is, files beginning with underscore)?

Comment: @niksy I think not, at least with reasonable amount of hacking. You should ask in [SASS issue queue](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues).

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the comment in an unused @mixin - not an ideal fix but it works.

```
@mixin ignore {
    /*
      COMMENT
    */
}
```