# How to make sass-only comments

Tags: css, sass

Is there a way to make `sass-only` comments in `SASS`? You know, so the output `.css` files don't have those comments

For example,

```
/* global variables */

$mainColor: #666;

/* Layout */
body {...}
```

will output

```
/* global variables */
/* Layout */
body {...}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three options for you to consider.

1) Use single-line comments starting with `//`, just like **heylookltsme** already suggested:

```
// This comment will not be included 
// in the compiled css!
```

2) Compile SASS using the *compressed* [output style](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#output_style). Then traditional `/* ... */` comments will not get their way into CSS.

Compiling with different output styles can be done with vanilla SASS but i also recommend trying [Compass](http://compass-style.org/help/).

Note that you can override the output style and force a comment to always appear in the resulting CSS code by starting it with an exclaimation mark:

```
/*!I really want this to appear in CSS at all times.*/
```

3) With Compass, you can make SASS omit all comments: both `// ...` and `/* ... */`.  I've explained how to do that in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15766439/901944

You should have a really good reason to go that way though.

Answer (score 4):

Single line comments will not be included in the compiled css, using //

```
// This comment will not be included 
// in the compiled css!
```

http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#comments