# Importing SCSS Without Comments

Tags: css, sass

Can I import a SCSS file, into another SCSS, without including the multiline (`/* */`) comments?

I have a `site.scss` file that is importing a `_baseline.scss` stylesheet (which is a custom CSS reset style sheet). In both files I have a large block comment:

```
/**
  *
  * DO NOT MODIFY CSS FILE: This file is part of a SCSS/CSS pair. CSS content is
  * automatically generated by the Sass compiler, only the '.scss' file is to be
  * modified. Any changes made directly to the CSS will be lost.
  *
  */
```

The goal being to prevent developers from editing the CSS file in the code repository. I want this in each file, since each file can/will be touched independently.

However, when I save my `site.scss` file I get this message twice!

Is there a way I can flag the comments in `_baseline.scss` to not be imported when I bring them into `site.scss`?

Comment: Any reason not to use `//` for comments?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to ignore multiline comments in sass?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720434/how-to-ignore-multiline-comments-in-sass)

Comment: @HashemQolami, the single line comments would also be removed in the resulting `.css` file. I want my "do not modify css file" statement to show up in the css file too.

Comment: I also don't want to ignore the multiline in the resulting `.css` output file (which is what the possible duplicate seems to be about). I want my comments preserved in the `.css`, but not imported into the `site.scss` file.

Comment: Why do you have those comments in _baseline.scss? Since it is a partial presumably it is never used unless included in another file.

Comment: @steveax - Huh. Good point! I've stupidly assumed I need to include the `_baseline.css` file in source control. I can probably add an exception to just ignore `_*.css` in the appropriate directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can possibly create `_css-notice.scss` which you include at the top of site.scss and there you place your notice:

```
/**
  *
  * DO NOT MODIFY CSS FILE: This file is part of a SCSS/CSS pair. CSS content is
  * automatically generated by the Sass compiler, only the '.scss' file is to be
  * modified. Any changes made directly to the CSS will be lost.
  *
  */
```

Remove the notice from all of your other files.

Additionally  you could make the `site.scss` an import only file without specifying anything else like it is in bootstrap for instance:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss