# How to ignore comments in sass partial files?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm using SASS and I have partial file for variables: _variables.scss. 
Above some group of variables, I'm using a comments. For ex.

```
/* Colors */
$primary_red: #c02323;
$dark_red: #84000f;
$blue_bg: #007eb6;
```

When using partials, the code is ignored in the css file, but the comments are showing:

[image]

Is there any way how to prevent them to show?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ignore multiline comments in sass?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720434/how-to-ignore-multiline-comments-in-sass)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use inline comments, they won't show up in your compiled file.

For example:

```
// Colors
```

Answer (score -1):

I use //------colors------//.
Probably overkill, but I like to have my comments not blend in so much so I can see them.